# Cassandra Not Starting Up

Tags: cassandra

```
[root@PPWFMD509 bin]# ./cassandra -f
Unrecognized VM option 'StringTableSize=1000003'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

running on jdk1.6_11 version.

Comment: Is there an environment variable set, either JAVA_OPTIONS or _JAVA_OPTIONS? If so, add that to your post.

Comment: No. for jdk.17 it worked.

Answer (score 5):

If it is Cassandra 2 then it needs JDK 1.7.